# Spring Rest controller retrive an image - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to retrieve an image from Spring RestController
I have two methods   getPictureById2 and getPictureById
getPictureById2 is just a test method I added

I have spring version:
    4.0.5.RELEASE

getPictureById2 - (the test method) is working fantastic and printing:

```
{"YES, ITS ":"working Wed Feb 21 16:56:31 EST 2018!"}
```

For the the other method getPictureById, I am not able to break in it or see any print from it,  this is the error I am getting:

**HTTP Status 400 - type Status report
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.15**

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/image")
public class ImageApi{

    @RequestMapping("/getPictureById2/{pictureId}")
     public ResponseEntity<String>  getPictureById2(@PathVariable("pictureId") String pictureId){
        return Helper.getRsponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,"{\"YES, ITS \":\"working "+new Date()+"!\"}");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/getPictureById/{pictureId}")
     public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>  getPictureById(@PathVariable("pictureId") String pictureId) {

        String fileName = pictureId +".jpg";


            try {
                ClassPathResource picFile = new ClassPathResource(Helper.IMG_PATH+  fileName);
                  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                  headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);             
                  headers.setContentLength(picFile.contentLength());
                  ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> response = new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(
                                    new InputStreamResource(picFile.getInputStream()), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
                  return response;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("getPictureById error " + e.getMessage(),e) ;
            }

    return null;
    }
```

Comment: Showing **how** (always meaning code :) ) are you testing it would be great to understand the problem

Comment: its just a URL get <server>/image/getPictureById2/100

Comment: Did you configure the servlet for multipart in you WebApplicationInitializer?
 MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(TMP_DIR,
        MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE * 2, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE / 2);
    restServlet.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);